# React Hotkeys Hook - shortcut (ctrl, alt , +)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, hotkeys

How to add the shortcut (ctrl+alt+'+') in the React Hotkeys Hook. The below code is not working

```
useHotkeys('ctrl + alt + +', ()=>{
    console.log('clicked')
  })
```

but (ctrl + alt + -) is working fine

I tried the below code, It is not working but for 'ctrl + alt + +', but If we try for 'ctrl + alt + -' then it is working

```
useHotkeys('ctrl + alt + +', ()=>{
    console.log('clicked')
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use + because is the default combinationKey

https://react-hotkeys-hook.vercel.app/docs/api/use-hotkeys#options

try with the code below

```
useHotkeys(
    "ctrl , alt , +",
    () => {
      console.log("clicked");
    },
    {
      combinationKey: ","
    }
  );
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to implement this shortcut 'ctrl + alt + +' using any other packages?

Comment: I tried the code, but it does not work if we change the default option. I tried changing the combinationKey and the splitKey but got no results.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by using this package: **@reecelucas/react-use-hotkeys**

```
npm install @reecelucas/react-use-hotkeys
```

It works for all my scenarios.

Thank you, @Miguel, for your suggestions.